# Using global keyword inside public function issue

Tags: php, function, public

I am trying to use a global keyword inside of a public function.

Here is what I have, you'll see variable $memberID, and I have it commented out but can echo out the memberID below it, but when it's used inside of a function, it doesn't recognize it.

I have "global $memberID;" inside function, but won't work.

```
<?php
$memberID = $_GET['memberID'];
// echo $memberID;

class DB_Functions {
    private $db_conx;
    function __construct() {
        include_once ('db_conx.php');
        $this->db_conx = DBC::connect();
    }
    function __destruct() {}

    /**
     * Start SERIES ------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    public function getActiveSeries() {
        global $memberID;
    // $memberID = '1';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE isActive = 'y' AND USER_ID = '$memberID'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db_conx,$sql);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you access `$_GET['memberID']` directly inside the `getActiveSeries` method?

Comment: Don't use global, just pass it as a parameter to the function. And your code is vulnerable to SQL injection when you concatenate variables into your SQL like that.

Comment: That works that way, but I have about 30+ other public functions, I was just trying to make calling the database query USER_ID based on global variable $memberID.

Comment: Why don't you pass the member ID in the construct function. Use object oriented programming features. The global keyword is bad practice

Comment: I figured the global keyword was bad practice which was why I was looking for other suggestions here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, just so I understand. Are you saying to use "$_GET['memberID']" in my SQL query? If I do that, do you see other vulnerabilities for SQL injections?

Comment: No, that still has the same vulnerability. Bind the value to a prepared statement instead. See this example in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples

Answer (score 1):

Try use object oriented programming.

```
$class = new DB_Functions($_GET['memberID']);//this goes in the construct function. 


class DB_Functions {
public $memberID;

public function __construct($memberid = null) {
$this->memberID = (int) $memberid; 
}
#access the member ID as $this->memberID

public function getActiveSeries() {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE isActive = 'y' AND USER_ID = '$this->memberID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db_conx,$sql);
    return $result;
}

}
```

The advantage of the above approach is that the member ID would be available through out this class for each instance. Meaning you don't have to pass the member ID to each function in the class.  All you have to do is pass the member ID when you instantiate the class and then access it as `$this->memberID` in any function in the class

Also kindly start using prepared statements as you are using an api that supports it

Comment: Great, I like this option. Could you lay it out based on the code I sent. I just mean with the other stuff I have in construct function, etc....

Comment: Just merge my changes with what you have. It doesn't help you learn if you copy and paste.

Comment: I understand and I agree. I guess what I was getting at, do I keep my "function __construct()" and add the one you made "public function __construct($memberid = null)" I have tried both and both seem to fail.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['memberID']` is already a global you can access it directly in your method.

```
public function getActiveSeries() {
    $memberId = filter_var($_GET['memberId'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM series WHERE isActive = 'y' AND USER_ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $memberId);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have done that and got it to work, but in one of the comments above, that’s still vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: What you are trying to do is also vulnerable to SQL injections, you need to sanitize your input with `filter_var` and use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php